# Replacement for c style loop with modulo

Tags: swift

Since C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift, what is the best way to achieve the following:

```
for var i = startIndex; i != endIndex; i = (i + 1) % arrCount {
}
```

(I want to iterate the array, but start from somewhere at the middle and continue until I'll reach the index I started from)

Edit:
startIndex > endIndex

Comment: How does `startIndex` relate to `endIndex`?

Comment: you could implement your own `SequenceType` for iteration with modulo.

Comment: @TimVermeulen I've added the relation between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"while" should be the best:

```
var i = startIndex
while i != endIndex {
    i = (i + 1) % arrCount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the original array pretty easily, see this example:

```
let array = [3,4,5,6,7]
let startIndex = 3
let endIndex = 2

let head = array[0..<endIndex] // [3, 4]
let tail = array[startIndex..<array.count] // [6, 7]
let shiftedArray = tail + head // [6, 7, 3, 4]

for element in shiftedArray {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a custom SequenceType & associated GeneratorType, as suggested by [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) in a comment above.

On the plus side, this sequence is really rather nicely readable and flexible. For instance:

```
let startIndex = 3
let endIndex = 2
let array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

ModuloSequence(start: startIndex, end: endIndex, divisor: array.count).map {
    array[$0]
}
```

On the minus side, it's rather verbose to implement (my take on it is, anyway):

```
struct ModuloSequenceGenerator : GeneratorType {
    let end:Int, divisor:Int
    private var dividend:Int?

    init(start:Int, end:Int, divisor:Int) {
        self.dividend = start
        self.end = end
        self.divisor = divisor
    }

    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        guard let c = dividend where c != end else {
            return nil
        }
        dividend = (c + 1) % divisor
        return dividend
    }
}

struct ModuloSequence : SequenceType {
    let start:Int, end:Int, divisor:Int

    func generate() -> ModuloSequenceGenerator {
        return ModuloSequenceGenerator(start: start, end: end, divisor: divisor)
    }
}
```